# Oracle - PL/SQL - INSERT ALL with SELECT as VALUES

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I have a question regarding the code to be used to put 3 tables in relationship, starting from an XML file.

The 3 tables are Organisation, Publication and the Fact table to put them in relationship.

Below the tables structures:

```
PUBLICATION
------------
CD_PUB (primary key, progressive number automatically generated when a new record has been inserted, thus the value is not taken from the XML file)
CD_REC 

ORGANISATION
------------
CD_ORG (primary key, progressive number automatically generated when a new record has been inserted, thus the value is not taken from the XML file)

FT_PUB_ORG
------------
CD_FT (primary key, progressive number automatically generated when a new record has been inserted, thus the value is not taken from the XML file)
CD_ORG (I want to insert here the related code of the Organisation)
```

The code I'm using is:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP



 INSERT INTO WOS_DM_PUBLICATION (
                                CD_UID 
                              , DT_COVERDATE 
                              , FL_HAS_ABSTRACT 
                              , QT_ISSUE 
                              , DT_PUBMONTH 
                              , CD_PUBTYPE 
                              , DT_PUBYEAR 
                              , DT_SORTDATE 
                              , QT_VOL 
                              , CD_PAGE_BEGIN 
                              , CD_PAGE_END 
                              , CD_PAGE 
                              , QT_PAGE_COUNT 
                              , QT_TITLE_COUNT 
                              , LB_TITLE_SOURCE 
                              , LB_TITLE_SERIES 
                              , LB_TITLE_SOURCE_ABBREV 
                              , LB_TITLE_ABBREV_ISO 
                              , LB_TITLE_ABBREV_11 
                              , LB_TITLE_ABBREV_29 
                              , LB_TITLE_ITEM                
                              , LB_TITLE_BOOK_SERIES 
                              , CD_ACCESSION_NO 
                              , CD_LANG_TYPE 
                              , CD_LANG_NORM 
                              , CD_IDS 
                              , FL_IDS_AVAIL 
                              , CD_BIB_ID 
                              , CD_BIB_PAGECOUNT                                 
                            )


                   select 
                             RecUid.cd_uid
                           , PubInfo.*
                           , Titles.*
                           , Title.*
                           , Acc_no.*
                           , Lang.*
                           , Lang2.*
                           , Items.*

                    from testtable2 t
                    cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                     'records/REC'
                      passing t.xml_file 
                      columns 
                              CD_UID varchar2(200) path 'UID',
                                     names xmltype path 'static_data/summary',
                                  identifi xmltype path 'dynamic_data/cluster_related',
                                      lang xmltype path 'static_data/fullrecord_metadata',
                                      item xmltype path 'static_data/item'
                        ) RecUid

                      cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                     'summary/pub_info'
                      passing RecUid.names
                      columns                           
                           DT_COVERDATE varchar2(20) path '@coverdate',
                        FL_HAS_ABSTRACT varchar2(20) path '@has_abstract',
                               QT_ISSUE varchar2(20) path '@issue',
                            DT_PUBMONTH varchar2(20) path '@pubmonth',
                             CD_PUBTYPE varchar2(20) path '@pubtype',
                             DT_PUBYEAR varchar2(20) path '@pubyear',
                            DT_SORTDATE varchar2(20) path '@sortdate',
                                 QT_VOL varchar2(20) path '@vol',
                          CD_PAGE_BEGIN varchar2(20) path 'page/@begin',
                            CD_PAGE_END varchar2(20) path 'page/@end',
                                CD_PAGE varchar2(20) path 'page',
                          CD_PAGE_COUNT varchar2(20) path 'page/@page_count'    
                        ) PubInfo

                    cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                     'summary/titles'
                       passing RecUid.names
                      columns     
                         QT_TITLE_COUNT varchar2(20) path '@count'
                       ) Titles

                    cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                     'summary/titles'
                       passing RecUid.names
                      columns                                 
                               LB_TITLE_SOURCE varchar2(200) path 'title[@type="source"]',
                               LB_TITLE_SERIES varchar2(200) path 'title[@type="series"]',
                        LB_TITLE_SOURCE_ABBREV varchar2(200) path 'title[@type="source_abbrev"]',
                           LB_TITLE_ABBREV_ISO varchar2(200) path 'title[@type="abbrev_iso"]',
                            LB_TITLE_ABBREV_11 varchar2(200) path 'title[@type="abbrev_11"]',
                            LB_TITLE_ABBREV_29 varchar2(200) path 'title[@type="abbrev_29"]',
                                 LB_TITLE_ITEM varchar2(200) path 'title[@type="item"]',
                          LB_TITLE_BOOK_SERIES varchar2(200) path 'title[@type="book_series"]'
                       ) Title

                    cross join  xmltable( xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                     'cluster_related/identifiers/identifier[@type="accession_no"]'
                      passing RecUid.identifi
                      columns 
                         CD_ACCESSION_NO varchar2(200) path '@value'
                        )   Acc_no   

                    cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                     'fullrecord_metadata/languages/language[@type="primary"]'
                      passing RecUid.lang
                      columns 
                         CD_LANG_TYPE varchar2(200) path '.'
                         --CD_LANG_NORM varchar2(200) path 'normalized_languages/language'
                        )   Lang

                    cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                     'fullrecord_metadata/normalized_languages/language[@type="primary"]'
                      passing RecUid.lang
                      columns 
                         CD_LANG_NORM varchar2(200) path '.'
                        )   Lang2

                    cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                     'item'
                      passing RecUid.item
                      columns 
                              CD_IDS VARCHAR(200) path 'ids',
                        FL_IDS_AVAIL VARCHAR(2)   path 'ids/@avail',
                           CD_BIB_ID VARCHAR(50)  path 'bib_id',
                    CD_BIB_PAGECOUNT VARCHAR(25)  path 'bib_pagecount'

                      )   Items  ;

      INSERT     INTO  WOS_DM_ORGANISATION (
                                      LB_LEGAL_NAME 
                                    ,   CD_ADD_NO 
                                    ,   LB_FULL_ADDRESS 
                                    ,   CD_CITY 
                                    ,   CD_STATE 
                                    ,   CD_COUNTRY_NAME 
                         --           , CD_POSTAL_CODE 
                                    ,   CD_ZIP_LOCATION 
                                    , FL_PARENT
                                       )

                          select                              
                                    Organis.* 
                                 ,  'Y' FL_PARENT 

                          from testtable2 t
                          cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
                           'records/REC/static_data/fullrecord_metadata/addresses/address_name'
                            passing t.xml_file 
                            columns 

                               LB_LEGAL_NAME varchar2(200) path 'address_spec/organizations/organization',
                              CD_ADD_NO varchar2(200) path 'address_spec/@addr_no',
                               LB_FULL_ADDRESS varchar2(200) path 'address_spec/full_address',
                               CD_CITY varchar2(200) path 'address_spec/city',
                               CD_STATE varchar2(200) path 'address_spec/state',  
                               CD_COUNTRY_NAME varchar2(200) path 'address_spec/country',
                              -- CD_POSTAL_CODE varchar2(200) path 'address_spec/zip/.'--,
                               CD_ZIP_LOCAZION varchar2(200) path 'address_spec/@location'
                               )   Organis ;
  INSERT INTO FT_PUB_ORG_TEST

                (  
                   CD_PUB_ID ,
                   CD_ORG_ID )
                VALUES
                (

                WOS_DM_PUBLICATION_id_seq.currval,
                WOS_DM_ORGANISATION_id_seq.currval);

  x := x + 1;
END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
     END;
```

The problem is that with this code I have only the final values in the FT table, but I want all the relationships.
I've already tryed with INSERT ALL statement but it seems not to work with SELECT as values.

Please consider that the loop was only a try but it doesn't work as I need.

Comment: I believe that you are saying that the `insert` into `WOS_DM_PUBLICATION` inserts n rows with a primary key of `CD_PUB_ID` using a trigger and the `WOS_DM_PUBLICATION_id_seq` sequence.  Similarly, the `insert` into `WOS_DM_ORGANISATION` inserts exactly n rows with a primary key of `CD_ORG_ID` using a trigger and the `WOS_DM_ORGANISATION_id_seq` sequence.  After both inserts run, for i between 1 and n, you want to insert a row into `FT_PUB_ORG_TEST` with the primary key from the i-th key from each of the two previous `insert` statements.  Is that right?

Comment: It would seem unlikely that you really want to rely on matching up rows from the two `insert` operations based on position order.  Certainly not without adding `order by` clauses to both of your statements.  I would expect that you'd really want to match the data up by some other key.  But I have no idea what that key would be.

Comment: @JustinCave I confirm your guess. Do you have any idea about how correct the code?

Comment: OK.  So are you saying that you really want to rely on the arbitrary order in which rows are returned by the two `select` statements to figure out which rows to join?  Without an `order by`, that's very dangerous.  Unless for some reason you don't care which rows get mapped to each other in the mapping table so long as every row gets mapped?

Comment: @JustinCave I see what you mean... we could use the CD_UID as link between the 2 tables. Do you have any idea about how to correct my statement considering the CD_UID field in the FT_PUB_ORG_TEST table?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd want to create a collection type

```
CREATE TYPE num_tbl
    AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

In your PL/SQL block, you'd declare a couple of collections

```
DECLARE
  l_publication_keys num_tbl;
  l_organization_keys num_tbl;
BEGIN
  ...
```

Your `INSERT` statements would then use the `RETURNING` clause to load the generated primary keys into a collection

```
INSERT INTO WOS_DM_PUBLICATION( <<columns>> )
  SELECT <<whatever>>
    FROM <<whatever>>
   ORDER BY <<something>>
  RETURNING cd_pub_id 
       BULK COLLECT INTO l_publication_keys;
```

You'd do the same thing with the `WOS_DM_ORGANISATION` insert statement.  You could then insert into the mapping table by iterating over the collections

```
FOR j in 1 .. l_publication_keys.count
LOOP
  INSERT INTO FT_PUB_ORG_TEST (  
                   CD_PUB_ID ,
                   CD_ORG_ID )
                VALUES (
                   l_publication_keys(j),
                   l_organization_keys(j)
                );
END LOOP;
```

This assumes that both collections will always have exactly the same number of elements and that you always want to match up the j-th row from each `insert` statement.  That seems risky unless there is something about your data that you haven't mentioned.

If you want to use the `cd_uid` column to correlate data in the two collections, you'd probably want to create an object type for your collection.

```
CREATE TYPE uid_obj
  AS OBJECT (
    cd_uid integer, -- I'm guessing at the data type
    key    integer
);

CREATE TYPE uid_tbl
  AS TABLE OF uid_obj;
```

Your local variables would then be collections of the new type

```
DECLARE
  l_publication_keys uid_tbl;
  l_organization_keys uid_tbl;
BEGIN
```

Your `RETURNING` clause would change to

```
RETURNING uid_obj( cd_uid, cd_pub_id )
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_publication_keys;
```

And then the last `INSERT` could be something like

```
INSERT INTO FT_PUB_ORG_TEST (  
                       CD_PUB_ID ,
                       CD_ORG_ID )
  SELECT p.key,
         o.key
    FROM TABLE( l_publication_keys ) p
         JOIN TABLE( l_organization_keys ) o
           ON( p.uid_cd = o.uid_cd );
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Probably I misunderstood before, but you are right when you say that it's strange to have one row for each Pub and each Org, indeed we have more Org for each Pub. So one Publication can have only one CD_UID but more Organisation. Does your code works anyvay?

Comment: @newinIT - The second approach with the `uid_obj` object should work.  Assuming that I've understood all your requirements which is a rather large assumption.  In the future, posting a reproducible test case (a simplified problem that includes the (simplified) table definitions, data, and code we need to replicate the issue along with the desired output would be very helpful to clarify requirements.  Otherwise, we're left guessing or we have to go back and forth in comments (which are limited)

Comment: I really thank you for your patience and explanation, I've been trying to let the code work but without success... I have the follow errors: `PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended - PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UID_OBJ" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "UID_OBJ" to continue. PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BULK" when expecting one of the following:` I don't really understand where the problem is.